# Recursive function run on False condition returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the below function doing [fuzzymatching](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)  on people's names.  It takes a dictionary with keys that are names I'm matching on.  It's expensive to create the dictionary and I will use the function in notebooks where a may already have the dictionary created...so I want to leave the option to not create it each time I run the function.  For that, I've defaulted it to be None so I can pass it if needed.  If I don't have it initialized already, it will do so on its own.

Note that `get_player_dict()` is the function that returns the dictionary:

```
def match_player_names(input_name, player_dict=None):
    matches = []
    if player_dict:
        for player in list(map(lambda player: player.lower(), player_dict.keys())):
            if fuzz.partial_ratio(input_name, player) > 75:
                matches.append(player)
    else:
        match_player_names(input_name, player_dict=get_player_dict())

    return matches
```

This returns nothing (`matches` is `[]`).  However, if I simply copy/paste the code in the `True` condition and replace the recursion with an initialization of the dictionary, it works fine (like below):

```
    else:
        for player in list(map(lambda player: player.lower(), player_dict.keys())):
            if fuzz.partial_ratio(input_name, player) > 75:
                matches.append(player)
```

Any ideas why the recursion wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You're not capturing the return value from the call inside the `else` statement, so `matches` remains empty.

```
else:
    matches = match_player_names(input_name, player_dict=get_player_dict())
```

or simply

```
else:
    return match_player_names(input_name, player_dict=get_player_dict())
```